# what is the meaning of source:match("%d*") in lua?

Tags: lua

```
-- Parse speed value as kilometers by hours.
function Measure.parse_value_speed(source)
  local n = tonumber(source:match("%d*"))
  if n then
    if string.match(source, "mph") or string.match(source, "mp/h") then
      n = n * miles_to_kilometers
    end
    return n
  end
end
```

I'm confused with the "*" after %d in the above code. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1), [`string.match`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match). You can avoid a lot of questions by looking up the documentation first. Please do not misunderstand be, asking questions is fine. However, (at least) minimal effort is always welcome, too.

Comment: Thank you. I mean the "*" behind the "%d" in tonumber(source:match("%d*"))

Comment: `source:match("%d*")` is short for `source.match(source, "%d*")` which in turns is `string.match(source, "%d*")` (via metatable)(correct as long as `source` is a string). Meaning of `%d` and `*` is described in the first link.

Answer (score 0):

It is all in the Lua Reference Manual!

```
source:match("%d*")
```

Is syntactic sugar for `string.match(source, "%d*")`

See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10

> **string.match(s, pattern [, init])**   Looks for the first match of pattern (see [§6.4.1](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match)) in the string s. If it finds one, then match
>   returns the captures from the pattern; otherwise it returns nil. If
>   pattern specifies no captures, then the whole match is returned. A
>   third, optional numeric argument init specifies where to start the
>   search; its default value is 1 and can be negative.